# Set margin using geometry package

Tags: pdftex, geometry

I am trying to alter the margins of a certain page in my document to have different margins from rest of document. So I'm using the `geometry` package. However, the margins of my document look weird even when I call `\restoregeometry`. In my latex class file I have a line like this:

```
\usepackage{vmargin} \setmarginsrb           { 1.5in}  % left margin
                        { 0.6in}  % top margin
                        { 1.0in}  % right margin
                        { 0.8in}  % bottom margin
                        {  20pt}  % head height
                        {0.25in}  % head sep
                        {   9pt}  % foot height
                        { 0.3in}  % foot sep
```

I try to replicate this using `geometry` but without any luck

```
\usepackage[ left=1.5in,
top=0.6in,
right=1.0in,
bottom=0.8in,
headsep=0.25in,
headheight=20pt,
heightrounded,
a4paper]
{geometry}
```

What am I missing?

UPDATE

I've created a minimum working example. If you comment out the geometry bits, it works, otherwise, it looks weird.

```
\documentclass{ecsthesis}      % Use the Thesis Style 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%\usepackage[ left=1.5in, 
%top=0.6in, 
%right=1.0in, 
%bottom=0.8in, 
%headsep=0.25in, 
%headheight=20pt, 
%heightrounded, 
%a4paper] 
%{geometry}        
    \begin{document}        
    %\restoregeometry

    \frontmatter \title{Title page title page}

    \authors    {\texorpdfstring
                 {\href{mailto:}{Name}}
                 {Name}
                } \addresses  {\groupname\\\deptname\\\univname} \date       {\today} \subject    {} \keywords   {} \maketitle

    \end{document}
```

Comment: it would be easier to answer if you provided test documents using the two forms and say how they differ

Comment: `vmargin` is outdated (and weird)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Question updated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `geometry` the settings in the preamble are for the whole document. `\restoregeometry` after `\begin{document}` has no effect, since it sets the layout back to the way it was set up in the preamble.

You need to use `\newgeometry` before the pages with changed margins and `\restoregeometry` after them.

In the following code, I did not use your class, but it nevertheless shows how to change and restore the layout mid document.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}      

\begin{document}        
\frontmatter
\title{Title page title page}
\author{Some One}
\maketitle

\mainmatter
\chapter{Normal Pages}
\lipsum[1-20]

\newgeometry{left=1.5in, 
top=0.6in, 
right=1.0in, 
bottom=0.8in, 
headsep=0.25in, 
headheight=20pt, 
heightrounded}
\chapter{Special Pages}
\lipsum[1-20]

\restoregeometry
\chapter{Normal Pages again}
\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```